# Changing gl_PointSize of OpenVR's color_cube_actor.py causes Python to crash?

Tags: python, opengl, openvr

I am using this [color_cube_actor.py](https://github.com/cmbruns/pyopenvr/blob/master/src/openvr/color_cube_actor.py) file and am able to run the [hello_qt_controllers.py](https://github.com/cmbruns/pyopenvr/blob/master/src/samples/qt_pyside/hello_qt_controllers.py) example while using my [HTC Vive](https://www.vive.com/us/) and I do see the colored cube and I am able to walk around using roomscale, so all is ok.

[image]

I would like to start learning how to change the buffer data in real time from Python.

To start I removed a lot of the unnecessary parts of the GLSL program and modified it to render the faceless vertices as 10px white dots.

[image]

Trying to feed a value in from a Python loop to have the vertex dot size change I was experimenting with [this example](https://github.com/anttisalonen/pyopengl-tests/blob/master/cube.py) and I modified my project in accordance with the `drawWithoutVBOs()` style.

Using a simple static non-changing variable (`layout(location = 8) uniform float Size = 10;`) my program works and produces the above image.

But, if I use a "varying" variable (`layout(location = 8) in float Size;`) then Python will completely crashe without an error.

*Sourcecode for project*

```
#!/bin/env python

# file color_cube_actor.py

from textwrap import dedent
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from OpenGL.GL import *  # @UnusedWildImport # this comment squelches an IDE warning
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram
from pyqtgraph.opengl.shaders import getShaderProgram


class ColorCubeActor(object):
    """
    Draws a cube

       2________ 3
       /|      /|
     6/_|____7/ |
      | |_____|_|
      | /0    | /1
      |/______|/
      4       5
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.shader = 0

    def init_gl(self):
        vertex_shader = compileShader(dedent(
            """
            #version 450 core

            layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 Projection = mat4(1);
            layout(location = 4) uniform mat4 ModelView = mat4(1);
            //layout(location = 8) in float Size; //This causes Python to crash!
            layout(location = 8) uniform float Size = 10;

            vec3 UNIT_CUBE[8] = vec3[8](
              vec3(-1.0, -0.0, -1.0), // 0: lower left rear
              vec3(+1.0, -0.0, -1.0), // 1: lower right rear
              vec3(-1.0, +2.0, -1.0), // 2: upper left rear
              vec3(+1.0, +2.0, -1.0), // 3: upper right rear
              vec3(-1.0, -0.0, +1.0), // 4: lower left front
              vec3(+1.0, -0.0, +1.0), // 5: lower right front
              vec3(-1.0, +2.0, +1.0), // 6: upper left front
              vec3(+1.0, +2.0, +1.0)  // 7: upper right front
            );

            out vec3 _color;

            void main() {
              _color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
              gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * vec4(UNIT_CUBE[gl_VertexID] * 0.3, 1.0);

              gl_PointSize = Size;
            }
            """),
            GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

        fragment_shader = compileShader(dedent(
            """
            #version 450 core

            in vec3 _color;
            out vec4 FragColor;

            void main() {
              FragColor = vec4(_color, 1.0);
            }
            """),
            GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        self.shader = compileProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        self.vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)

        glBindAttribLocation(self.shader, 8, "Size")
        glLinkProgram(self.shader)

        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE) #allow the program to specify the point size
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def setPointSize(self):
        size = [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(8)
        glVertexAttribPointer(8, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, size)

    def display_gl(self, modelview, projection):
        glUseProgram(self.shader)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) #| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, False, projection)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(4, 1, False, modelview)

        self.setPointSize()
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 8 )

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

    def dispose_gl(self):
        glDeleteProgram(self.shader)
        self.shader = 0
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, (self.vao,))
        self.vao = 0
```

I'm not sure if I have missed something or if possibly by my project using the QT backend as opposed to PyGame then there are subtle differences between my environment and other examples which is causing a problem??

I was hoping someone here could help me figure out why feeding a value to gl_PointSize will cause Python to crash. I am also very interested in ways I could modify the buffer data (positions, point sizes, ect..) in realtime while using the PyOpenVR libraries?

Thanks for any help!

---

[UPDATE]

This is my latest project which I modified by copying from the [GLSL Tutorial – Attribute Variables](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/attribute-variables/). This now only produces a blank screen in both pyGame and pySide QT.

```
#!/bin/env python

# file color_cube_actor.py

import time
from textwrap import dedent
import numpy as np

from OpenGL.GL import *  # @UnusedWildImport # this comment squelches an IDE warning
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class ColorCubeActor(object):

    array_size = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.program = 0
        self.scale = 0

        self.indices = np.ascontiguousarray( np.arange(self.array_size), dtype=np.int)
        self.colors = np.ascontiguousarray( np.tile(np.array([0.0,1.0,0.0]), (self.array_size,1)), dtype=np.float) #a bunch of green vertices
        self.sizes = np.ascontiguousarray( np.ones(self.array_size)*10, dtype=np.float)

    def init_gl(self):
        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE) #allow the program to specify the point size

        vertex_shader = compileShader(dedent("""
            #version 450 core

            layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 Projection = mat4(1);
            layout(location = 4) uniform mat4 ModelView = mat4(1);

            in vec3 ptPosition;
            in float ptSize;
            in vec3 ptColor;

            out vec3 _color;

            void main()
            {
                _color = ptColor; //vec3(0.2, 0.5, 1.0); //light blue
                gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * vec4(ptPosition, 1.0);

                //use normalized device coordinates to calculate the PointSize of a vertex based on it's distance from the perspective camera.
                //https://www.gamedev.net/topic/574695-gl_points-distance-attenuation/#
                vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w ; // perspective divide.
                float zDist = 1.0-ndc.z ; // 1 is close (right up in your face,)
                // 0 is far (at the far plane)
                gl_PointSize = ptSize*zDist ; // between 0 and 50 now.

            }
            """), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

        fragment_shader = compileShader(dedent("""
            #version 450 core

            in vec3 _color;
            out vec4 FragColor;

            void main() {
                FragColor = vec4(_color, 1.0); //just pass a color to the vertex (results in a rectangle pixel)
            }
            """), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        self.program = compileProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

        #setup the vao and bind buffers (example: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/attribute-variables/ )
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        self.ptSize = glGenBuffers(1) #bind buffer for point sizes
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ptSize) #GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is the buffer type we use to feed attributes
        ptSize_pointer = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "ptSize") #get the location of attribute "ptSize" from self.program
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.sizes.nbytes, self.sizes, GL_STREAM_DRAW) #feed the buffer, and let OpenGL know that we don't plan to
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ptSize_pointer) #Enable the attribute at that location
        glVertexAttribPointer(ptSize_pointer, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0) #Tell OpenGL what the array contains:

        self.ptColor = glGenBuffers(1) #bind buffer for point colors
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ptColor) #GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is the buffer type we use to feed attributes
        ptColor_pointer = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "ptColor") #get the location of attribute "ptSize" from self.program
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.colors.nbytes, self.colors, GL_STREAM_DRAW) #feed the buffer, and let OpenGL know that we don't plan to
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ptColor_pointer) #Enable the attribute at that location
        glVertexAttribPointer(ptColor_pointer, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0) #Tell OpenGL what the array contains:

    def setPoints(self, modelview, projection):
        self.scale += 0.0005

        #create dataset https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html
        theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, self.array_size)
        z = np.linspace(-2, 2, self.array_size)
        r = z**2 + 1
        x = r * np.sin(theta)
        y = r * np.cos(theta)
        plot = np.ascontiguousarray(np.dstack((x,y,z)) * self.scale, dtype=np.float)

        self.ptPosition = glGenBuffers(1) #bind buffer for positions and copy data into buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ptPosition) #GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is the buffer type we use to feed attributes
        ptPosition_pointer = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "ptPosition") #get the location of attribute "ptSize" from self.program
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, plot.nbytes, plot, GL_STREAM_DRAW) #feed the buffer, and let OpenGL know that we don't plan to
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ptPosition_pointer) #Enable the attribute at that location
        glVertexAttribPointer(ptPosition_pointer, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0)#Tell OpenGL what the array contains:

        glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, False, projection)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(4, 1, False, modelview)

        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, self.array_size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.indices)

    def display_gl(self, modelview, projection):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) #| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glUseProgram(self.program)
        self.setPoints(modelview, projection)

    def dispose_gl(self):
        glDeleteProgram(self.program)
        self.program = 0

    def main(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)
        self.init_gl()

        projection = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
            [ 0.75752085,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.],
            [ 0.        ,  0.68160856,  0.        ,  0.],
            [ 0.05516453, -0.00299519, -1.00040019, -1.],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.20008004,  0.]
        ])
        modelview = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
            [ 0.99030989,  0.04490654,  0.13141415,  0.],
            [-0.01430531,  0.9742285 , -0.22510922,  0.],
            [-0.13813627,  0.22104797,  0.9654305 ,  0.],
            [-0.12975544, -0.9294402 , -1.06236947,  1.]
        ])

        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < 5: #5 second animation
            self.display_gl( modelview, projection)
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ColorCubeActor()
    t.main()
```

Also thank you all again for the help and patients! I know I am very inexperienced with OpenGL and really appreciate all the suggestions.

---

[UPDATE]

Learning OpenGL has probably been one of the hardest things I have tried to do in a very long time. I've now spent four days just trying to set the buffers in OpenGL 4.5 and I have made almost no progress and I just feel stuck in a rut.

Here's an example of some code I wrote (It does not specify version 4.5). As per Derhass's suggestion I have tried to use VBOs i this file and they seem to work until specifying the `#version 450 core` where all I get is lots of depreciation errors and 1282's. Again because it does not target OpenGL 4.5 I don't think I can use it with OpenVR (No idea why that is though?).

[image]

```
#!/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import time
import numpy as np
from textwrap import dedent

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

##############################################################################
# OpenGL funcs
##############################################################################
buffers=None
shader = None
def init_gl():
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE) #allow the program to specify the point size

    global shader, buffers

    vertex_shader = compileShader(dedent('''

        uniform mat4 Projection = mat4(1);
        uniform mat4 ModelView = mat4(1);

        varying out vec3 _color;

        void main() {
            _color = gl_Color;
            gl_Position =  Projection * ModelView * gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

            vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w ; // perspective divide.
            float zDist = 1.0-ndc.z ; // 1 is close (right up in your face,)
            // 0 is far (at the far plane)
            gl_PointSize = 25*zDist ; // between 0 and 50 now.

        }
        '''), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragment_shader = compileShader(dedent('''

        in vec3 _color;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(_color, 1.0); //gl_Color;
        }
        '''), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    shader = compileProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

    buffers=create_vbo()

yaw=0
pitch=0
def draw():
    global yaw, pitch
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)# | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    yaw+=0.39
    pitch+=0.27
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0)
    glRotatef(pitch, 1, 0, 0)

    setPoints()
    glFlush()

##############################################################################
# vertices
##############################################################################
array_size = 100
scale = 0.15

#create dataset https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, array_size)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, array_size)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)

vertices = np.dstack((x,y,z)) * scale
colors = np.tile(np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0]), (array_size,1)) #a bunch of green vertices
indices=np.arange(array_size)


def create_vbo():
    buffers = glGenBuffers(3)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0])
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            vertices.nbytes,  # byte size
            (ctypes.c_float*len(vertices.flat))(*vertices.flat),
            GL_STREAM_DRAW)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1])
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            colors.nbytes, # byte size
            (ctypes.c_float*len(colors.flat))(*colors.flat),
            GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[2])
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            indices.nbytes, # byte size
            (ctypes.c_uint*len(indices.flat))(*indices.flat),
            GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    return buffers

def draw_vbo():
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[2]);
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, indices.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


def setPoints():
    global shader

    glUseProgram(shader)
    draw_vbo()

    projection = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
        [ 0.75752085,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.],
        [ 0.        ,  0.68160856,  0.        ,  0.],
        [ 0.05516453, -0.00299519, -1.00040019, -1.],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.20008004,  0.]
    ])
    modelview = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
        [ 0.99030989,  0.04490654,  0.13141415,  0.],
        [-0.01430531,  0.9742285 , -0.22510922,  0.],
        [-0.13813627,  0.22104797,  0.9654305 ,  0.],
        [-0.12975544, -0.9294402 , -1.06236947,  1.]
    ])

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "Projection"), 1, False, projection)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "ModelView"), 1, False, modelview)

    glUseProgram(0)

##############################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)

    init_gl()

    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 5: #5 second animation
        draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

So I tried rewriting it into a Python Class() but even though it looks identical, for some reason I only see one vertex moving around and the rest are who knows where:

```
#!/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import time
import numpy as np
from textwrap import dedent

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileShader, compileProgram

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class ObjectActor(object):
    array_size = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.buffers=None
        self.shader=None

        self.vertices = self.get_vertices()
        self.colors = np.tile(np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0]), (self.array_size,1)) #a bunch of green vertices
        self.indices = np.arange(self.array_size)

    def init_gl(self):
        ##############################################################################
        # OpenGL funcs
        ##############################################################################

        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE) #allow the program to specify the point size

        vertex_shader = compileShader(dedent('''

            uniform mat4 Projection = mat4(1);
            uniform mat4 ModelView = mat4(1);

            varying out vec3 _color;

            void main() {
                _color = gl_Color;
                gl_Position =  Projection * ModelView * gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

                vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w ; // perspective divide.
                float zDist = 1.0-ndc.z ; // 1 is close (right up in your face,)
                // 0 is far (at the far plane)
                gl_PointSize = 25*zDist ; // between 0 and 50 now.

            }
            '''), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment_shader = compileShader(dedent('''

            in vec3 _color;

            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(_color, 1.0); //gl_Color;
            }
            '''), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        self.shader = compileProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

        self.create_vbo()

    def display_gl(self, modelview, projection):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.setPoints(modelview, projection)
        glFlush()

    def get_vertices(self):
        ##############################################################################
        # vertices
        ##############################################################################
        scale = 0.15
        theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, self.array_size)
        z = np.linspace(-2, 2, self.array_size)
        r = z**2 + 1
        x = r * np.sin(theta)
        y = r * np.cos(theta)
        return np.dstack((x,y,z)) * scale

    def create_vbo(self):
        self.buffers = glGenBuffers(3)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[0])
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                self.vertices.nbytes,  # byte size
                (ctypes.c_float*len(self.vertices.flat))(*self.vertices.flat),
                GL_STREAM_DRAW)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[1])
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                self.colors.nbytes, # byte size
                (ctypes.c_float*len(self.colors.flat))(*self.colors.flat),
                GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[2])
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                self.indices.nbytes, # byte size
                (ctypes.c_float*len(self.indices.flat))(*self.indices.flat),
                GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    def draw_vbo(self):
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[0])
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[1])
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[2])
        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, self.indices.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    def setPoints(self, modelview, projection):
        glUseProgram(self.shader)

        self.draw_vbo()

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader, "Projection"), 1, False, projection)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader, "ModelView"), 1, False, modelview)

        glUseProgram(0)

    def main(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)
        self.init_gl()

        projection = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
            [ 0.75752085,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.],
            [ 0.        ,  0.68160856,  0.        ,  0.],
            [ 0.05516453, -0.00299519, -1.00040019, -1.],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.20008004,  0.]
        ])
        modelview = np.array([#the matrix generated captured while using HTC Vive
            [ 0.99030989,  0.04490654,  0.13141415,  0.],
            [-0.01430531,  0.9742285 , -0.22510922,  0.],
            [-0.13813627,  0.22104797,  0.9654305 ,  0.],
            [-0.12975544, -0.9294402 , -1.06236947,  1.]
        ])

        yaw=0
        pitch=0
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < 5: #5 second animation

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
            glLoadIdentity()
            yaw+=0.39
            pitch+=0.27
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0)
            glRotatef(pitch, 1, 0, 0)

            self.display_gl(modelview, projection)

            pygame.display.flip()

##############################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ObjectActor()
    t.main()
```

At this point I am definitely considering the possibility that either something is very broken in the way PyOpenGL works or I'm just incapable of figuring out how to use it. Either way its a real bummer..

Comment: Have you considered checking for errors? I see that you compile&link a program, but you never check to see if that succeeded. Granted, Python's GL wrapper may do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid and very likely to crash.

`glVertexAttribPointer` will teat the last parameter as an *byte offset* into the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` object. If you want to specify some client memory pointer, you must make sure to have that binding target set to 0. However, your code does `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)` right before.

Now `self.vbo` is actually the name of a valid buffer object, but one for which you never created any storage. THe result is that you just set up some completely invalid pointer for the GL, and it does indeed crash when it tries to dereference this.

It is not clear which OpenGL context version and - more importantly - profile you use. In a core profile, using client-side vertex arrays is not possible any more, you have to transfer your data into a VBO first. In a compatiblity profile or legacy context, you might work around this crash by just making sure to `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)` before setting the attrib pointer.

Comment: I just tried removing all calls to bind the vbo and vao and then by using PyGame for render window I was able for some reason to actually get it to work and I could feed vert size to the program? But if I try same code while using OpenVR and QT I get a 1282 errors. Also, earlier I did try `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)` before setting the attrib pointer but it didn't appear to have much of an effect.

Comment: Well, you might use different context versions. You really shouldn't use such deprecated stuff anyway.

Comment: I printed the output of  `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` from both methods and there is a difference. PyGame gl_version = `4.5.0 NVIDIA 378.92` and PySide QT gl_version = `4.1.0 NVIDIA 378.92`. Could that be the problem? Can the version be changed programmatically?

Comment: Well, the version number is less interesting than the `GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK`. I tmight as well be the case that your qt application is using a core profile there. But instead of trying to switch that to a compat profile, I strongly recommend to make your code core-profile compatible instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran `print glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK)` and can see that PyGame = 0 and PySideQT = 1. Are there ways to determine what in my code is not core-profile compatible?

Comment: So that bit is indeed the core profile bit. As to the parts not being core-profile compatible: I already told you that in my answer: you cannot use client-side vertex arrays. YOu have to use a VBO as the source for the attribute array.